# In general, could any ad-hoc relationship of constants be useful?

Tags: soft-question, units, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

In general; if one creates an ad-hoc relationship of constants, can we use it to solve equations OR is it just an abstract/artificial math construct?

I'm a grad student and as we all know, these ad-hoc constants are very easy to make, but are they useful?

Sometimes I think that I'm chasing my own tail...

[R0^73*w0^73*e0^2/(c0^68*h0^74*A0^2*G0*N0^73)=23/10390 http://www.sendspace.com/pro/dl/rbvvix](http://www.sendspace.com/pro/dl/rbvvix)

Granted that the example is an artificial relationship, and has an error of a few parts per billion; still this type of ratio seems both unit and Prius invariant.  The constants aren't going to change, hence the ratio should stay the same in all units.

[maple sheet http://www.sendspace.com/pro/dl/7chckl](http://www.sendspace.com/pro/dl/7chckl)

In summary, if one creates an artificial ad-hoc relationship; then it is abusing dimensional analysis by definition?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44017/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44875/2451

Answer (score 6):

A clear case of "abusing dimensional analysis". Perhaps not the first time that a physics stack-exchange question is answered by [xkcd](http://xkcd.com/):

[image: abusing dimensional analysis]

Comment: I disagree.  I believe that I understand your thought process but point out that my equation has no prius terms.

I dunno, talk about dumbing down. Don't they teach recreational mathematics anymore?
 - The Doctor